# How can I separate tuples into columns in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these values in dataset in a pandas dataframe column

```
col1
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]
[[13,14],[15,16],[17,18],[19,20],[21,22],[23,24]]
```

I want to get 6 elements as list in new columns as rows.

This is the columns that I want to get.

```
col2                    col3
[1,3,5,7,9,11]          [2,4,6,8,10,12]
[13,15,17,19,21,23]     [14,16,18,20,22,24]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and the DataFrame constructor:

```
df[['col2', 'col3']] = pd.DataFrame([list(map(list, zip(*l))) for l in df['col1']])
```

Another approach with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
a = np.dstack(df['col1'].to_numpy())
df['col2'] = a[:,0].T.tolist()
df['col3'] = a[:,1].T.tolist()
```

Output:

```
                                                           col1                      col2                      col3
0           [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]       [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]      [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
1  [[13, 14], [15, 16], [17, 18], [19, 20], [21, 22], [23, 24]]  [13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23]  [14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]
```